# Error:expected expression before 'int' when casting float or double into integer in C

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

This code is to show the primer number between 500 and 1000.

When I build this code on gcc 6.2.1 it return an error but when I build it on Visual Studio 2015 it's successful.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    int primer_number(int a)
    {
      int i, m = 0;
      for (i = 2; i<int(sqrt(double(a))); i++)
      {
        if (a%i == 0) return m = 1;
      }
    return m;
    }

   int main(void)
   {
    int i;
    for (i = 500; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        if (primer_number(i) == 0) printf("%d\n", i);
    }
   }
```

Screenshot Here [gcc 6.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y0QP.png)

```
x=3.14159265359;
float y=1.41421;
int z=int(x);
z=int(y);
```

Your error messages:

```
cfile.c:605:10: error: expected expression before ‘int’
    int z=int(x);
          ^~~
cfile.c:606:6: error: expected expression before ‘int’
    z=int(y);
      ^~~
```

Comment: This is your problem: `int(sqrt(double(a)))`. Try: `(int)sqrt((double)a)`

Comment: It looks like you are compiling it as C++ in one case (Visual C++) and as C in the other (gcc). It fails because you are using C++ casts which are not valid in C.

Comment: BTW, `sqrt` should only be computed once (before the loop). Or test on `i*i <= a`; and you should declare `bool primer_number(int a)`

Comment: and by the way, it should be `i <=` not `i <`, otherwise you will consider any  number that is square of a prime as a prime. Definitely, the test SHOULD be `i*i <= a` as per @BasileStarynkevitch.

Answer (score 4):

`int(sqrt(double(a)))` is a valid expression in C++ but not in C. Perhaps Visual Studio 2015 has some non-standard extensions that allows such an expression in C or you are compiling the file as though it is a C++ file.

```
double x=3.14159265359;
float y=1.41421;
int z=(int)x;  //correct syntax to cast double to int
z=(int)y;  // there should be no syntax error
```

Change it to `(int)sqrt(a)`.

```
for (i = 2; i< (int)sqrt(a)); i++)
{
  if (a%i == 0) return m = 1;
}
```

<strike>**Suggestions for further cleanup**</strike>

You can get better performance by moving the call to `sqrt(a)` out of the loop. Also, you don't need the variable `m` at all.

```
int primer_number(int a)
{
   int i;
   int end = (int)sqrt(a);
   for (i = 2; i < end; i++)
   {
     if (a%i == 0) return 1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**PS** The logic used in the function is wrong. You can use a slightly modified logic:

```
int primer_number(int a)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 2; i*i <= a; i++)
   {
      if (a%i == 0) return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this classify `9` as a non-prime number? I dont think so. I suggest `for (i = 2; i*i <= a; ++i)`

Comment: @A.S.H, it sure does.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I mean it should not, but it does. I edited my question :) (added "non-")

Comment: AFAIK Visual Studio treats C code always as "special" C++ Code, because it has no C-compiler.